# How to use porerties file in Jenkins multiple branches feature by Config File Provider?

Tags: jenkins

I use Jenkins for CI/CD service, because some security reason, I need to store some key value in private way.

I tried to use `Config File Provider Plugin` in the Multiple Branches Project.

I add a config file by the plugin like

[image]

and copied uuid as `fileId` in Jenkinsfile

```
stage('feature') {
          when{
            branch 'feature/*'
          }
          steps {
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'e83d3c64-459d-4f9e-9b3a-6c1c44f459a1', variable: 'MY_PROPS')]) {
                echo "Printing MY_PROPS:"
                echo "${MY_PROPS}"
                sh "echo ${MY_PROPS.NETLIFY_SITE_ID}"
            }
          }
        }
```

I got the return:
[image]

I thought the fileId is not as picture indicated.

How could I got the Key Value from the file I added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `MY_PROPS` is a temporary file which is a copy of your config file, you need to load it before inspect property in it.

```
steps {
  script {
    configFileProvider([
        configFile(fileId: 'e83d3c64-459d-4f9e-9b3a-6c1c44f459a1', variable: 'MY_PROPS')
    ]) {
       def props = readProperties file: "${MY_PROPS}"
       sh "echo ${props.NETLIFY_SITE_ID}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !, But there is a fly in the ointment `def props = readProperties` need to be placed in nest of `script` like `script { def props = readProperties file...}`